# Change default rootfs file permissions to 750 instead of 755 in yocto

Tags: linux, permissions, operating-system, embedded-linux, yocto

How do I change the yocto rootfs files having 755 permissions to 750. I don't want other  to have access to rootfs. Where is the default file / directory permissions set in yocto?

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is to create a small function in your image recipe, and then call that function from ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND to do what you're asking about.

```
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "chmod_rootfs;"

chmod_rootfs()
{
    chmod 0750 ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/<files to change>
}
```

That should fix up the specifics.

Comment: On my build your suggestion throws a ParseError which can be resolved by changing the fcn definition to bring the opening curly to the same line as chmod_rootfs()